# Aiohttp how to log request body

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp and want to log the raw request in ClientSession before it's sent. I saw that for requests module, it is doable: [Python requests - print entire http request (raw)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw)

But when I tried finding for aiohttp, I can only find for request headers, but what I want is the body: [Dumping the request headers with aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185775/dumping-the-request-headers-with-aiohttp)

I have looked into the source code for tracing but all I can find is the ClientResponse class being used and no instances of ClientRequest class being used: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/tracing.py

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the request body using tracing as the following:

```
async def on_request_chunk_sent(session, trace_config_ctx, chunk):
        print("Chunk sent request", chunk)

trace_config = aiohttp.TraceConfig()
trace_config.on_request_chunk_sent.append(on_request_chunk_sent)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config]) as session:
...
```

For more info, refer to the [docs](https://on_request_chunk_sent).