retrieve full headers and url with params in the case of any aiohttps exception where the request is contructed
I would like to access the full request data including automatic headers and the url with query params without this hacky global variable. In my actual use case, Headers may be passed either to the session or the request. I would like to be able to access this information in the case of any exception after the request object has been initialized (much like a requests.PreparedRequest object). Is there another modification to ClientRequest which would accomplish this?
I have tried a number of solutions which TraceConfig which have not been successful. From this github issue, it seems that a CustomClientRequest is the correct approach.
import aiohttp
import asyncio


class CustomRequest(aiohttp.ClientRequest):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        global request_data
        request_data = {
            "headers": self.headers,
            "method": self.method,
            "url": self.url,
            "body": str(self.body),
        }


async def main():
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(request_class=CustomRequest) as client:
            async with client.post(
                "https://badlink.io", data="a=b", params={"x": "y"}, headers={"a": "b"}
            ) as resp:
                await resp.text()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    print(request_data)


asyncio.run(main())

result
{
    'headers': {
        'Host': 'badlink.io',
        'a': 'b',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'User-Agent': 'Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.9.5',
        'Content-Length': '3',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    },
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://badlink.io/?x=y',
    'body': 'a=b'
}

p.s. not looking for an aiohttps monkey patch.

My first thought is that you might want something from the tracing API: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#aiohttp-client-tracing

@sam-bull unfortunately, on_request_start is the only tracing event which takes place before the request is sent. however, this takes place before a request object is initialized so it doesn't have automatic headers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185775/dumping-the-request-headers-with-aiohttp

Solved with custom TCPConnector class which saves request history. Passed to session via ClientSession(connector=my_connector)
